# Handle Email Verification Check with auth0/nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, auth0, email-verification

I am using the library auth0/nextjs. I am trying to handle the email verification. I have access to the `email_verification` variable. If not verified, it will redirect to the page `/please-verifiy-your-email`.

At the moment I am using `handleCallback` method which is provided by auth0/nextjs.

Code:

```
const afterCallback = (req, res, session, state) => {
  if (!session.user.email_verified) {
    res.status(200).redirect('/please-verifiy-your-email')
  }

  return session;
};

export default auth0.handleAuth({
    async login(req, res) {
      try {
        await auth0.handleLogin(req, res, {
          authorizationParams: {
            audience: 'https://dev-okz2bacx.us.auth0.com/api/v2/',
            scope: 'openid profile email read:branding'
          },
          returnTo: "/dashboard"
        });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(error.status || 400).end(error.message);
      }
    },
    async callback(req, res) {
      try {
        await auth0.handleCallback(req, res, { afterCallback });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.message);
      }
    }
});
```

How can I make sure, the user is still logged in, to get his email for a resend or the possibility to change his email.

He also needs the chance to do a new sign up , because when I will call `api/auth/login` after login with the unverified email, it will redirect automatically to `/please-verifiy-your-email`. I guess the session is not killed and auth0 goes back redirecting even tho I didn’t had the chance to sign up again.

Would be really cool if I get a few inputs.

It would solve the problem if I could log in the user and then it would redirect to `/please-verifiy-your-email`. I would be able to get his email address, name for further functions like resend verification. Right now I call `api/auth/me` I get:

> {"error":"not_authenticated","description":"The user does not have an
> active session or is not authenticated"}

Comment: Hi, in my reactjs application I was using auth0 rule to force email verification.
With nextjs auth0 rule doesn't work properly, user state somehow remains in the browser.
With your solution as you said you can't access user email address. Could you find a solution?

Comment: @BySlasherr were you able to resolve this issue? I am trying a similar example. However, I am not getting any value in the `session` arg of the `afterCallback `  method.
Also, I am confused with the `returnTo` option in the `login` method. Not sure what that is supposed to do. Docs say its the url to which the user should be directed after login. However, isn't the `callbackUrl` exactly for this purpose?
Auth0 NextJs docs and examples are really ppor :(. Being struggling with this for 2days now